# Draw cap for custom TubeGeometry to make it look solid

Tags: three.js

I've extend `TubeGeometry` to have varying `radius` based on `beginRadius` and `endRadius`. I'm trying to draw cap on both ends to make it look like solid.

Drawing cap at ending point is not working. It is not drawing slanting cap

https://jsfiddle.net/arundhaj/ysfr8jb0/

Comment: You know start and end points of your arc, you know points of start and end tubular segments. Having this, create an additional indices and add to `.index`. Or create additional circle buffer geometries of the same segmentation as your torus, give them position, rotation and scale of respective end points of torus, then merget those three geometries. [Example](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/end-caps-of-tubegeometry/9655/6?u=prisoner849) Creativity is up to you.

Comment: @prisoner849 Thank you for the idea. I've now extended `TorusGeometry` and added cap https://jsfiddle.net/arundhaj/7cs9kvrj/